# Is it possible to have different xibs for different target for one particular viewController?

Tags: ios, xcode

My project has 2 different targets. And I need 2 different themes for each one. I know this is possible by manually specifying the changes in the viewController itself. I was wondering whether the same was possible from with in the xib  itself. I'm using XCode 6.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 different XIBs based on your target. But you have to include preprocessor macros in your Build Settings. When you are invoking the class, based on the preprocessor Mac, instantiate the XIB that you want and present that view controller. You cannot do target based designs in XIB/storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write if else condition whether it is iPhone 4/4s or 5 like this.
IS_IPHONE4 - it is macro which check and return bool value.

```
if(IS_IPHONE4)
{
self.viewController =
    [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControlleriPhone4" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
self.viewController =
    [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControlleriPhone5" bundle:nil];
}
```